# Monitoring an API endpoint for changes

Tags: javascript, rest, web, axios, monitoring

I am trying to write a monitor for changes in data returned by a specific endpoint. I need to make api calls on an interval of one request per second. Below is a simplified version of my code:

`async function t() {     let res = await axios(config)     console.log(res)     return }`

`for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) t()`

`setInterval(() => {     t() }, 100);`

`setIntervalAsync(() => {     t() }, 100);`

Currently, the simple for loop works perfectly for what I am looking for, with the exception of a set delay. What I ideally want is to use some for of setInterval. The issue there is that setInterval is somehow messing up the requests, such that maybe one will go through, but the rest fail. Why is this happening, and how should I solve this?